# Intellij IDEA using the wrong comment style

Tags: html, intellij-idea, comments

I'm using IDEA 12.1.4, and when I try to insert a line/block comment into an HTML file (`*.html`), it inserts a jinja2 style comment.

E.g.

```
<div class="form-group">
```

becomes...

```
{# <div class="form-group"> #}
```

I tried manually setting the Template Data Language to HTML, and jinja files should only be recognized when they have an extension of `.jinja`.  Is there some other setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go here to change template language settings:

File -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Python Template Languages -> Template Language -> %set_appropriate%.

Comment: In PyCharm 4, it is in Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Python Template Languages -> Template Language set to None

Comment: This was beautiful, thanks a lot. Jinja2 commenting screwed up my yaml scripts

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem occurred because my project was configured as Flask Project.  That added the following configuration to my Project.iml file:

```
<component name="TemplatesService">
    <option name="TEMPLATE_CONFIGURATION" value="Jinja2" />
    <option name="TEMPLATE_FOLDERS">
        <list>
            <option value="$MODULE_DIR$/project/app/assets/partials" />
        </list>
    </option>
</component>
```

When I manually deleted this section and closed/reopened the project, I was able to insert HTML comments.